# SparkSQL Receive more than 10000 documents from Elasticsearch with es-hadoop

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get all the documents from index in Elasticsearch with SparkSQL and send them to another index using es-hadoop library. In the future it will be used for middle processing, so i need the SparkSQL for the data processing.

I developed the simple class in java that supposed to do this kind of operation (if i understand it right)

```
    Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARN);
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/opt/test");
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("es-test")
            .setMaster("local[10]");
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

    Map<String, String> sourceTaskConfig = new HashMap<>();
    sourceTaskConfig.put("es.nodes", "localhost");
    sourceTaskConfig.put("es.port.size", "9200");
    sourceTaskConfig.put("es.resource", "index1");

    Dataset<Row> dataframe = JavaEsSparkSQL.esDF(new  SQLContext(sparkSession), sourceTaskConfig);

    //Here will be data processing

    Map<String, String> destinationTaskConfig = new HashMap<>();
    destinationTaskConfig.put("es.nodes", "localhost");
    destinationTaskConfig.put("es.port.size", "9200");

    JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(dataframe, "index2", destinationTaskConfig);
```

I expect that all my data from index1 will be moved to index2, but actually, i receive only 10000 documents and task stop. I already try to play with size limits in configuration.
I'll be more than happy, if someone could explain me what i do incorrect.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you share your maven info. Want to know which libraries and versions have you used.

Comment: Yes, exactly:)
  <pre><code>` <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency> `

Comment: @Kamal Strange but the site does not format the code:( So sorry for misformatting.

Comment: not a problem. Thanks for sharing the maven details. I will try something and let you know.